# Time complexity in backtracking algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, proof

I what to calculate the worst case, time complexity for this recursive function.

list is a list of m*n pieces.

matrix is a matrix of mxn to fill with this peaces.

```
Backtrack(list, matrix):
  if(matrix is complete) //O(1)
     return true
  from the list of m*n pieces, make a list of candidatePieces to put in the matrix. // O(m*n)
  for every candidatePiece // Worst case of n*m calls
      Put that piece in the matrix // O(1)
      if(Backtrack(list, matrix) is true)
           return true
```

What I guess is that the formula is something like:

T(n*m) = T(n*m - 1) + O(n*m) + O(1) = T(n*m - 1) + O(n*m)

Is this correct?

I can't use the master theorem, witch other method can I use to get a closed formula?

Comment: Do you ever take things out of the matrix? Do the candidate pieces ever not go in? When does `matrix is complete` return `true`?

Comment: My reason for asking is that the `for every candidatePiece` loop seems pointless if it never actually backtracks, which seems to be what Ashalynd assumes.

Answer (score 1):

If you unwind your formula, you'll get

```
T(n*m) = T(n*m-1)+O(n*m) = T(n*m-2)+O(n*m-1) + O(n*m) = ...
= O(n*m) + O(n*m-1) + O(n*m-2) +... + O(1) =>  ~ O(n^2*m^2)
```

But I wonder is that algorithm complete? It does not seem to return false at all.

Answer (score 0):

So we have:

```
Backtrack(list, matrix):
  if(matrix is complete) //O(1)
     return true
  from the list of m*n pieces, make a list of candidatePieces to put in the matrix. // O(m*n)
  for every candidatePiece // Worst case of n*m calls
      Put that piece in the matrix // O(1)
      if(Backtrack(list, matrix) is true)
           return true
```

We assume worst-case behaviour, some `matrix is complete` is false for as long as possible. I'm going to assume this is up until `O(n·m)` insertions.

So consider `for every candidatePiece`. In order to get to the second item, you'll need `Backtrack(list, matrix) is true` to be false at least once. This requires termination other than by `return true`. As the only way to do that requires exhausting the loop, and that requires exhausting the loop (and so on), this can only happen if `candidatePiece` is **empty**.

I assume pieces can only be used once. In this case, there are `O(n·m)` things in the matrix. This means `matrix is complete` has returned `true`, so this actually doesn't let the loop run a second time.

If pieces don't run out, this is also obviously true.

We can then simplify to

```
Backtrack(list, matrix):
  if(matrix is complete)
     return true

  if(candidatePiece is not empty)
      Put the first piece in the matrix

      if(Backtrack(list, matrix) is true)
           return true
```

Then we have

```
T(n·m) = T(n·m - 1) + O(n·m)
```

as you said, which leads to Ashalynd's answer.

---

Assume instead that `matrix is complete` can return false even when the matrix is full. Assume also that pieces run out, so the matrix can never be over-full. I also assume that pieces are removed as appropriate.

- The outmost loop (loop 0) costs `O(n·m)` and runs the inner loop (loop 1) `n·m` times.
- The inner loop (loop 1) costs `O(n·m - 1)` and runs the inner inner loop (loop 2) `n·m -1` times.
- ...
- Loop `n·m - 1` costs `1` and runs loop `n·m` once.
- Loop `n·m` costs `0` (call overhead moves into loop `n·m - 1`) and terminates.

So, let `T(n·m)` be the cost for loop 0, and `T(0)` be the cost for loop `n·m`.

```
T(x) = O(x) + x · T(x - 1)
```

and [WolframAlpha solves this to be `O(Γ(x+1) + x·Γ(x, 1))`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T(x)+%3D+x+%2B+x+%C2%B7+T(x+-+1)).

By some research, this is equal to

```
O(x! + x· [ (x-1)! · e⁻¹ · eₓ₋₁(1) ])

= O(x!) + O(x· eₓ₋₁(1))

= O(x!) + O(x· ∑ 1/k! from k=0 to x-1)

= O(x!)
```

So for `x = n·m` we are talking `O((n·m)!)` time. That's pretty poor :/.